# SQL Max Group By Query Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have a quick question. How do I select the two values I need in one query? Currently I'm doing this, which works fine, but it's obviously running two queries when one should do the trick. I tried MAX(columnA) and GROUP BY ColumnB, but that returns multiple row. I only want one row returned.

```
DECLARE @biID  bigint  
, @dtThreshold      DateTime 

  SELECT @biID = MAX(biID)
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount WITH (NOLOCK)

  SELECT @dtThreshold = dtDateTime
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE biID = @biID
```

I would like both those variables to be set correctly in one query. How can I do that?

Thanks,
~ck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
DECLARE
  @biID bigint,
  @dtThreshold DateTime 

SELECT
  @dtThreshold = A.dtDateTime,
  @biID = B.biID
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(biID) biID
              FROM tbPricingCalculationCount) B
    ON A.biID = B.biID
```

If you're not using the biID elsewhere, you can even trim it to:

```
DECLARE
  @dtThreshold DateTime 

SELECT
  @dtThreshold = A.dtDateTime
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(biID) biID
              FROM tbPricingCalculationCount) B
    ON A.biID = B.biID
```

Answer (score 8):

can you not just do this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 @biID = biID, @dtThreshold = dtDateTime 
  FROM tbPricingCalculationCount WITH (NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY biID DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT TOP 1 @biID = biID, @dtThreshold = dtDateTime
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY biID desc
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns dtDateTime for the row with the largest biID:

```
SELECT t1.dtDateTime
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount t1
LEFT JOIN tbPricingCalculationCount t2
ON t2.biID > t1.biID
WHERE t2.biID IS NULL
```

If more than one row shares the same "largest" biID, then you need to limit the results to one using TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.dtDateTime
FROM tbPricingCalculationCount t1
LEFT JOIN tbPricingCalculationCount t2
ON t2.biID > t1.biID
WHERE t2.biID IS NULL
```

Comment: are you sure that even works? you can't join on a `<`, only an `=`, or have i missed something? also, what is the NULL WHERE clause about?

Comment: You can join on any criteria. Also, the NULL WHERE criteria says you want the row where there isn't a larger biID.

Comment: Wow.  That's a roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: @Chris, this is really efficient, assuming an index on the biID column.

Comment: @marcus, i'm interested : is it any more efficient than a simple order by desc?

Comment: @oedo, probably not. In this case, the simple `ORDER BY` with `TOP` is probably the best solution. It is often better than a subquery, though.